# How can I change my code so that when I slice a list, the last element is exclusive?

Tags: recursion, ocaml, slice

I'm trying to make a slicing function in OCaml and it sort of does what I want except that it doesn't exclude the last element in the list. I can see why it does that, but I'm not sure how to change my code so that it doesn't include the last element.

```
slice ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h"] 2 6;;
```

This is the code I'm testing and I can see that in my code, this is basically how the steps go.

```
slice ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h"] 2 6
slice ["b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h"] 1 5
slice ["c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h"] 0 4
```

and since i = 0 now, the function is done. But I'm not sure how to slice from the right. I want the output to be

```
["c"; "d"; "e"; "f"]
```

This is the code that I'm working with.

```
let rec slice lst i j = 
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> 
    if (j > List.length lst) then slice lst i (List.length lst) 
    else if i > j then []            
    else if i = 0 then h :: (slice t 0 (j - 1)) 
    else slice t (i - 1) (j - 1);;
```

Comment: Bit  of a latecomer suggestion, but when comparing the length of a list with an integer, you may want to use [`List.compare_length_with`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your second index is exclusive, it seems like you want to stop the recursion when i >= j rather than when i > j.